# Koa-generic-session add token

Tags: session, cookies, jwt, koa, httponly

I get JWT token from other api and then want to send it ti my node.js backend and write it in `httpOnly` cookie. 
How to add some data(JWT token) to `HttpOnly` cookie with koa-generic-session?

Answer (score 0):

koa uses the cookies module where options are simply passed.

docs https://github.com/pillarjs/cookies